# Project Euler Problem 87 Code gives wrong answer

Tags: java

I'm doing problem 87 of Project Euler, which reads as follows:

The smallest number expressible as the sum of a prime square, prime cube, and prime fourth power is 28. In fact, there are exactly four numbers below fifty that can be expressed in such a way:

28 = 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup>

33 = 3<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup>

49 = 5<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup>

47 = 2<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup>

How many numbers below fifty million can be expressed as the sum of a prime square, prime cube, and prime fourth power?

I used the following code:

```
public class primes {
    public static List<Integer> primeNumbersTill(int n) {
        List<Integer> primeNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
        if (n >= 2) {
            primeNumbers.add(2);
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                primeNumbers.add(i);
            }
        }
        return primeNumbers;
    }
    private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i*i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 50000000;
        List<Integer> ListofPrimes = primeNumbersTill(n);
        List<Integer> Squares = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> Cubes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> Fourth = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> Results = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < ListofPrimes.size(); i++) {
            if(Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),2) < n) {
                Squares.add((int) Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),2));
            }
            if(Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),3) < n) {
                Cubes.add((int) Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),3));
            }
            if(Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),4) < n) {
                Fourth.add((int) Math.pow(ListofPrimes.get(i),4));
            }
        }
            for(int j2 : Squares) {
                for(int j3 : Cubes) {
                    for(int j4 : Fourth) {
                        int sum = j2 + j3 + j4;
                        if(sum < n) {
                            Results.add(sum);
                        }
                    }
                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Results.size());

    }
}
```

The answer I get is 1 391 732, which is wrong. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you test? Did you calculate a few simple/low numbers on paper and compare?

Comment: for n = 50 my code returns 4, which is correct. I did not test it for any other numbers.

Comment: Maybe you should?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What are the results of your program for 29, 34, 48? The correct results for those should be obvious.

Comment: I tested it for 30, 35 and 48, which all give the correct answers of 1, 2 and 3. But testing for any higher numbers will become really hard, unless I'm able to find a list of numbers that are the sum of a prime square, cube and fourth power.

Comment: Or you could maybe do some work on paper. Or make a program which provides you with a table of square, cubes etc. to facilitate.

Comment: And if you did any other effort on this without describing it (like you did omit the rather sensbile testing you just described in a comment), please show the results and explain your thinking.

Comment: Your **`isPrime()` method is wrong**. Should be `i*i <= number`, otherwise it claims that numbers like `4`, `9`, `25`, `49`, ... are primes. --- Simply printing `ListofPrimes` should have shown you this flaw!!

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks! I did not inspect my ListofPrimes closely enough and just assumed it was right when I saw that the first few primes were correct. That was stupid.

Comment: It would have been found by following my proposal to do some paper work, the more complex part of which with lists generated by programs you wrote. The word you chose to describe that is too harsh. But you are supposed to do some own research before asking on StackOverflow, or at least after getting corresponding feedback. If you ask another question here please try to avoid the impression of "I know which hard work could get me some progress, but I prefer to let other people find the problem." The fact that here are people which can find such a problem by reading ocde does not change that.

Comment: Also, now that you know the solution, please make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = 2; i*i < number; i++) {`
Is supposed to be:
`for (int i = 2; i*i <= number; i++) {`